# Spring Boot wrong json value

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with returning an object in json format. This is my function to return a json object:

```
@GetMapping("/api/code/{n}")
@ResponseBody
public Code getCodeJson(@PathVariable int n) {
     Code code = codeList.get(n - 1);
     return code;
}
```

Objects of type Code are stored in a list, and I want to access them by the path variable n. The return looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"code":"{\"code\":\"hello world\"}","dateTime":"2021-10-05T16:49:31.911591"}
```

I don't know why this is happening, it should return a json that looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"code":"hello world","dateTime":"2021-10-05T16:49:31.911591"}
```

This is how I add code objects to the codeList

```
@PostMapping("/api/code/new")
@ResponseBody
public String addNewCode(@RequestBody String code) {
    Code newCode = new Code(code);
    codeList.add(newCode);
    return "{\n" + "\"id\" : \"" + newCode.getId() + "\"\n}";
}
```

This is Code.java class

```
    public class Code {
    
    private static int currentId = 1;
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public Code(String code) {
        this.id = currentId;
        this.code = code;
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        currentId++;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code of the codeList type and its assignment logic?

Comment: I just declare a field of CodeController class like this: private List<Code> codeList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Can you share `Code.java` also please

Comment: @PostMapping("/api/code/new"), can you share how do you post new code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the addNewCode to accept `Code` or new DTO `CodeDto` as the request body instead and use that instead. As of now you are getting the entire request body as string and assigning it to the code causing the current response.

```
@PostMapping("/api/code/new")
@ResponseBody
public String addNewCode(@RequestBody CodeDto code) {
    Code newCode = new Code(code.getCode());
    codeList.add(newCode);
    return "{\n" + "\"id\" : \"" + newCode.getId() + "\"\n}";
}
```

As you are passing `{"code":"hello world"}` as request body the above code will automatically deserialize it properly into an instance of `CodeDto` object with code attribute set to "hello world".

```
public class CodeDto {
    private String code;

    public CodeDto(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public CodeDto() {}

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it won't work since the POST request has to take a json with only the String code

Comment: Yes, I am passing {"code":"hello world"}. But when I tried your code I get an error saying :JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `platform.Code` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `platform.Code` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]

Comment: @TomekNowak You just have to add an all args constructor as shown in the answer. Can you please add it and see if that helps.

Comment: I can't do that, I want each Code instance to have its ID created automatically, and datetime is responsible for holding the exact time of creating the code. I think it makes sense to have these created as they are

Comment: Is there a way to take just that hello world part from the json {"code":"hello world"}?

Comment: @TomekNowak You can create a input Dto class as shown in the answer and use that for the `addNewCode` api or you'll have to use regex and extract it.

Comment: It doesn't work with the Dto class, I get the exact same error

Comment: @TomekNowak I missed the default constructor. Please see the updated code, add it and try once.

Comment: It works now, but I dont understand why xD thanks a lot!